# Just turn around from there or right there

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

If we want a person to turn around from where he's standing, and don't want that person to enter our room, will it be natural to say:

> Just turn around **from there.**
>
> Just turn around **right there.**

Are both of them equally natural? Can both of them be used and are they common (especially the first one).

Comment: Would you kindly do us the favor of checking these before posting? Turn around does not take from. The answers to these types of question are often in examples given in dictionaries.

Comment: So @Lambie you mean that "from" can't be used with it?

Comment: There is a good answer below.

Comment: In other words it isn't wrong but it's redundant...... @Lambie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just turn around right there.* is the better choice. It is more authoritative/commanding. Using *from there* is also possible, but has a different feel to it. It makes it sound like the important thing is **the position** and not the fact that you don't want them to enter. **From there**, not from another spot.

Comment: Has "from" been dropped in the second sentence? (The one you said sounds better)

Comment: No @Lambie , I mean has "from" been dropped in that sentence?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish *Just turn around right there* is, literally, the second example sentence you wrote in your question. So, it's repeating what you said, and not dropping anything. And using it is not *ungrammatical* but it's unidiomatic and odd.

Comment: I'm not talking about that @Jason Bassford,.I meant, that has "from" been dropped in that sentence, the one I used.... Actually I read it somewhere.

Comment: I think you mean, "Just turn around from right there." That works better than "Just turn around from there." It still has the emphasis. In fact, it has even more emphasis than "Just turn around right there." It has the feeling of "Don't take another step. Just turn around from where you are/right there." I can imagine the police saying it to someone. Hope that helps!